# Google Cloud YAML: How to find the commands or How to create a loadbalancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, load-balancing

I have a small issue I can't find how to fix.
Usually when you are coding, whether you are coding in python or a language like yaml, There are places you can find the commands or you have somewhere that you can find out what certain commands do.

Right now I want to create a http loadbalancer on the google cloud with deployment manager. Very basic stuff. But I just can't find the right command for the type or action.
Where does one find these things?

I hope you guys can help me. I'm feeling lost and googling doesn't help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [article](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/examples/v2/ha-service/README.md) you can create an LB using GCP Deployment Manager.